# Retrieving all notes from opportunity not working

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to retrieve all the notes from a specific opportunity. To me the query looks correct, but I have tried it on workbench and it still hasn't worked.

```
Select (Select Id From Notes) From Opportunity where id='123456789'
```

Edit1 : The ID I'm using is a valid ID

Edit2 : I've found that I wasn't querying the correct object in context to the label fields on the UI. The object I should be querying is `AttachedContentNote` which has a `Note Id` attached to it. I'm assuming then `AttachedContentNote` would be the parent and the `Note` would be the child.

Updated Query :

```
Select Id,(Select Title, Body from Notes) From AttachedContentNote where _________
```

Not sure what to fill out in the blank...

But I do know for sure, we have to play around with this parent-child relationship

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a valid Id?

Comment: Yeah, ID is valid for sure. Literally, copy pasted it

Comment: But not into the question here. Just wanted to verify.

Comment: Is there a chance, some notes are Private ? If true, only the note owner or a user with the “Modify All Data” permission can view the note or query it via the API. Note that if a user who does not have the “Modify All Data” permission sets this field to true on a note that they do not own, then they can no longer query, delete, or update the note.

Comment: Define "hasnt worked". Your query is fine, it should return 1 record in apex, an opportunity record, and then you would need to reference its Notes relationship to get the actual notes.

Comment: Private Notes are identified by IsPrivate field on Note Object. If IsPrivate is true, then a corresponding Note is Private Note.